# NoSuchMethodError exception with spring-data-redis

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-redis

Started getting the following exception, after upgrading release train to **Kay-RELEASE** of spring data.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration.<init>(RedisStandaloneConfiguration.java:61)
at org.egov.infra.config.redis.RedisServerConfiguration.redisConnectionFactory(RedisServerConfiguration.java:86)
at org.egov.infra.config.redis.RedisServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f89e20ba.CGLIB$redisConnectionFactory$1(<generated>)
at org.egov.infra.config.redis.RedisServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f89e20ba$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1ac62136.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
```

Have double checked all the jars dependency and neither there is duplicate nor different versions of jars exist. I'm using spring **4.3.12.RELEASE**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

spring-data Kay-RELEASE (aka 2.0.0) doesn't work with Spring v4.3.X <.
It only works with springframework v 5.0.0 >.

Answer (score 4):

I ran in the same problem today as well and resorted to asking on Gitter for help. They said:

> Spring Data 2.x does not work with Spring Boot 1.x
>   Please upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0 M5 or stay for the time being on Spring Data Redis 1.x

I believe that switching to Kay-RELEASE causes the use of 2.0.0.RELEASE of the other data libraries, causing the error.

So I switched spring-data-redis to 1.8.7.RELEASE and then I had to change
spring-data-commons to 1.13.8.RELEASE and spring-data-keyvalue to 1.2.8.RELEASE.

My POM file is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticache</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>elasticache</name>
  <description>Elasticache test</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-repo</id>
        <name>Spring Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-keyvalue</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticache</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.218</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Kay-RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Wilfred.. i'm are not using spring-boot and upgrading of spring-data-elasticsearch to the latest is a requirement for us to use latest elasticsearch client

Comment: In that case, perhaps you get more info at:
https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-data

They might be able to help.